# Photo Picker, after picking, image is too big

Tags: ios, swift, image

I predefined the image's size in attributes of 320 320[and gave it a aspect ratio constraint of 1:1

[image]

After I click the photo and select an image from the photo library:
[image]

What things should I be checking to make the photo stay in its 320 by 320 container?

Comment: show code of how u r loading the image into container!

Answer (score 1):

```
photo.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
[photo setClipsToBounds:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
view.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
```

after loading the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the `contentMode` of your `UIImageView` to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`.

You can do it in the code, or in Interface Builder (set the `mode` to `Aspect fit`):
[image: How to set imageview mode]

If you want, you can read the Apple's doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/ (on `Understanding How Images Are Scaled`)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, you don't really not both height/width and aspect ratio.

The two thing you will likely need to look at changing are the [contentMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/contentMode), and [clipsToBounds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds)

Answer (score 0):

Say this

```
imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
```

Then you will have the option to crop the image to have it fit